# CSS3: How can I get something that works like "absolute" but isn't?

Tags: html, css

I have a game going where i'm doing hitsplats to show up over your picture as you hit your opponent. I"m using the absolute position and this works but I encountered a problem. The problem being that if I resize the window or I am in another resolution, these spots are not how I orginally setup them up. Putting my hit splats in relative mode only moves stuff around. So how can I get my hitsplats in the center like they are now with Absolute, but yet not make them absolutely absolute? So they flow with the document?

```
#npchitbox {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1050px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    }
```

Here is HTML code

```
<div id="playerbox">
    <div id="hitbox"> </div>
```

Comment: Calculate the position of the opponent using `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`, and apply that. It might help to make the container positioned, too (but it really doesn’t matter as long as the offset parent is the same)

Comment: If you use JavaScript, this would be pretty trivial. You could bind a listener to the window resize event and set the CSS top and left based on the offset of `#playerbox`, as @minitech said.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show html and you're trying to center the hisplate only? If so do this

```
{
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to container's CSS for the hitsplat/hitbox div:

```
position:relative;
```

It should make the hitbox position absolutely to the container and not the window.

In theory it should shift the container from the browser window to whatever div/container you assign position:relative to.

Answer (score 0):

use resize event in jquery to fit it to exact position when window is resized

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "#hitbox" ).attr( "top", ($( window ).height()-50) +"px" ); 
//since 50 is the size of the box you are using
});
```